# On div hover, return it's left attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, function-call

I have 50 divs that have all the same class (.marker), and an id (#a1, #a2, ...).

Now I want, that if I hover over such a div a JavaScript function is called that returns the css-left attribute of the specific div:

```
function(divId){
return $(divId).css("left");
}
```

And I don't know how to do that without having to write a function call to every div.
I thought of something with  this.css("left"), that saves me typing work.

Thanks for your help in Advance...

Comment: Where do you want to return the left property value to?

Comment: to another function that sets a red dot into the middle of one of the divs...

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the code where you want to return the value to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a value from a click handler. But, you can change your approach to changing a variable

```
var currentLeft;
$('.marker').hover(function(){
    currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much... that was helpful... :) I know why i use stackoverflow... =P

Comment: @FabianSchneider, gald it helped :)

Comment: Just if you want to get it with hover, you can use the hover function instead click